# SharePoint, how do you programatically determine the storage size of a SPWeb?

Tags: sharepoint, spweb

Not of the site collection itself, but the individual SPWeb's.

Answer (score 7):

You should take a look at this blog entry by Alexander Meijers : [Size of SPWeb based on its Folders and Files](http://www.bloggix.com/blogs/microsoft/archive/2008/04/03/size-of-spweb-based-on-its-folders-and-files.aspx)

It provides a clever way of finding the size of an SPWeb or SPFolder by iterating through his content.

```
private long GetWebSize(SPWeb web)
{
    long total = 0;

    foreach (SPFolder folder in web.Folders)
    {
        total += GetFolderSize(folder);
    }

    foreach (SPWeb subweb in web.Webs)
    {
        total += GetWebSize(subweb);
        subweb.Dispose();
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: The article doesn't exist anymore and the code is missing GetFolderSize. There is a discussion with that code here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sharepointdevelopment/thread/0d066e9b-f6b9-49bc-b741-fcf7abdc854b

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes back to this question, here is the missing method:

```
private long GetFolderSize(SPFolder folder)
{
    long folderSize = 0;

    foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)
    {
        folderSize += file.Length;
    }

    foreach (SPFolder subfolder in folder.SubFolders)
    {
        folderSize += GetFolderSize(subfolder);
    }

    return folderSize;
}
```